# Using Beautiful Soup find_all() to find only when align=right

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to webscrape. I am trying to gather data from ESPN and save it to a file. Eventually, I want to parse the data so that each stat remains with the player. But every 10 players or so, three extra  tags are used which makes it hard to parse the data correctly. When I use find_all i try to use 'td' and then I want to get the data ONLY when align="right" (this is the data I want and removes the three extra  tags). However, when I try to add that to the function it does not work.

This is the website:

```
url_base = "http://www.espn.com/nhl/statistics/player/_/stat/points/sort/points/year/" + str(yr) + '/count/'
```

This is my code:

```
def player_count(page_nums):
    player_list = ['']
    num_start = 1
    for i in range(1, page_nums + 1):
        num_start += 40
        player_list.append(num_start)

    return player_list


def num_pages(num_strings):
    list_ = num_strings.split(" ")
    return list_[2]

year = []

for i in range(2001, 2019):
    year.append(i)

for yr in year:
    if yr == 2005:
        continue

    url_base = "http://www.espn.com/nhl/statistics/player/_/stat/points/sort/points/year/" + str(yr) + '/count/'

    for i in player_count_list:
        url = url_base + str(i)
        print(url)
        with urlopen(url) as page:
            html_doc = bS(page, 'html5lib')
            table_string = html_doc.find_all('td', {'align': 'right'})

            print(table_string)
            new_strings = []
            for td in table_string:
                new_strings.append(td.text)

        yr_file.append(new_strings)
```

After going through the documentation, it seems as though this should work:

```
html_doc.find_all('td', {'align': 'right'})
```

But i havent been able to get it.

Comment: did a quick check on the source [html](http://www.espn.com/nhl/statistics/player/_/stat/points/sort/points/year/2018/count/12). only tr elements seem to be aligned right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your URL and not `<td>` tags, but rows, `<tr>` with `align=right` contain useful data. To extract them, you can use following snippet:

```
yr_table = []
for i in player_count_list:
    url = url_base + str(i)
    print(url)
    with urlopen(url) as page:
        html_doc = bS(page, 'html5lib')

        for tr in html_doc.select('tr[align="right"]'):
            new_strings = []
            for td in tr.find_all('td'):
                new_strings.append(td.text.strip())
            yr_table.append(new_strings)

    pprint(yr_table, width=180)    # from pprint import pprint
```

Will print for example:

```
http://www.espn.com/nhl/statistics/player/_/stat/points/sort/points/year/2007/count/0
[['RK', 'PLAYER', 'TEAM', 'GP', 'G', 'A', 'PTS', '+/-', 'PIM', 'PTS/G', 'SOG', 'PCT', 'GWG', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'A'],
 ['1', 'Sidney Crosby, C', 'PIT', '79', '36', '84', '120', '10', '60', '1.52', '250', '14.4', '4', '13', '48', '0', '0'],
 ['2', 'Joe Thornton, C', 'SJ', '82', '22', '92', '114', '24', '44', '1.39', '213', '10.3', '5', '10', '44', '0', '0'],
 ['3', 'Vincent Lecavalier, C', 'TB', '82', '52', '56', '108', '2', '44', '1.32', '339', '15.3', '7', '16', '20', '5', '4'],
 ['4', 'Dany Heatley, LW', 'OTT', '82', '50', '55', '105', '31', '74', '1.28', '310', '16.1', '10', '17', '22', '3', '1'],
 ['5', 'Martin St. Louis, RW', 'TB', '82', '43', '59', '102', '7', '28', '1.24', '273', '15.8', '7', '14', '16', '5', '6'],
 ['6', 'Marian Hossa, RW', 'ATL', '82', '43', '57', '100', '18', '49', '1.22', '340', '12.6', '5', '17', '27', '3', '1'],
 ['', 'Joe Sakic, C', 'COL', '82', '36', '64', '100', '2', '46', '1.22', '258', '14.0', '4', '16', '27', '0', '0'],
 ['8', 'Jaromir Jagr, RW', 'NYR', '82', '30', '66', '96', '26', '78', '1.17', '324', '9.3', '5', '7', '34', '0', '0'],
 ['', 'Marc Savard, C', 'BOS', '82', '22', '74', '96', '-19', '96', '1.17', '221', '10.0', '3', '10', '39', '1', '0'],
 ['10', 'Daniel Briere, C', 'BUF', '81', '32', '63', '95', '17', '89', '1.17', '234', '13.7', '6', '9', '21', '0', '0'],
 ['RK', 'PLAYER', 'TEAM', 'GP', 'G', 'A', 'PTS', '+/-', 'PIM', 'PTS/G', 'SOG', 'PCT', 'GWG', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'A'],
 ['11', 'Teemu Selanne, RW', 'ANH', '82', '48', '46', '94', '26', '82', '1.15', '257', '18.7', '10', '25', '23', '0', '0'],
 ['', 'Jarome Iginla, RW', 'CGY', '70', '39', '55', '94', '12', '40', '1.34', '264', '14.8', '7', '13', '20', '1', '0'],
 ['13', 'Alex Ovechkin, LW', 'WAS', '82', '46', '46', '92', '-19', '52', '1.12', '392', '11.7', '8', '16', '21', '0', '0'],
 ['14', 'Olli Jokinen, C', 'FLA', '82', '39', '52', '91', '18', '78', '1.11', '351', '11.1', '8', '9', '19', '1', '0'],
 ['15', 'Jason Spezza, C', 'OTT', '67', '34', '53', '87', '19', '45', '1.30', '162', '21.0', '5', '13', '20', '1', '1'],
 ['', 'Daniel Alfredsson, RW', 'OTT', '77', '29', '58', '87', '42', '42', '1.13', '240', '12.1', '7', '7', '18', '2', '2'],
 ['', 'Pavel Datsyuk, C', 'DET', '79', '27', '60', '87', '36', '20', '1.10', '207', '13.0', '5', '5', '24', '2', '1'],
 ['18', 'Evgeni Malkin, C', 'PIT', '78', '33', '52', '85', '2', '80', '1.09', '242', '13.6', '6', '16', '24', '0', '0'],
 ['19', 'Thomas Vanek, LW', 'BUF', '82', '43', '41', '84', '47', '40', '1.02', '237', '18.1', '5', '15', '7', '0', '0'],
 ['', 'Daniel Sedin, LW', 'VAN', '81', '36', '48', '84', '19', '36', '1.04', '236', '15.3', '8', '16', '18', '0', '0'],
 ['RK', 'PLAYER', 'TEAM', 'GP', 'G', 'A', 'PTS', '+/-', 'PIM', 'PTS/G', 'SOG', 'PCT', 'GWG', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'A'],
 ['21', 'Ray Whitney, LW', 'CAR', '81', '32', '51', '83', '-5', '46', '1.02', '215', '14.9', '6', '6', '24', '0', '0'],
 ['', 'Andrew Brunette, LW', 'COL', '82', '27', '56', '83', '-8', '36', '1.01', '173', '15.6', '2', '9', '27', '0', '0'],
 ['', 'Michael Nylander, C', 'NYR', '79', '26', '57', '83', '12', '42', '1.05', '193', '13.5', '4', '14', '23', '0', '0'],
 ['24', "Rod Brind'Amour, C", 'CAR', '78', '26', '56', '82', '7', '46', '1.05', '181', '14.4', '5', '9', '21', '2', '3'],
 ['25', 'Alex Tanguay, LW', 'CGY', '81', '22', '59', '81', '12', '44', '1.00', '107', '20.6', '0', '5', '16', '0', '0'],
 ['', 'Henrik Sedin, C', 'VAN', '82', '10', '71', '81', '19', '66', '0.99', '134', '7.5', '2', '1', '34', '0', '0'],
 ['27', 'Michael Cammalleri, LW', 'LA', '81', '34', '46', '80', '5', '48', '0.99', '299', '11.4', '5', '16', '21', '0', '0'],
 ['', 'Slava Kozlov, LW', 'ATL', '81', '28', '52', '80', '9', '36', '0.99', '190', '14.7', '8', '8', '29', '0', '2'],
 ['29', 'Patrick Marleau, C', 'SJ', '77', '32', '46', '78', '9', '33', '1.01', '180', '17.8', '9', '14', '23', '0', '0'],
 ['', 'Paul Stastny, C', 'COL', '82', '28', '50', '78', '4', '42', '0.95', '185', '15.1', '6', '11', '20', '0', '1'],
 ['RK', 'PLAYER', 'TEAM', 'GP', 'G', 'A', 'PTS', '+/-', 'PIM', 'PTS/G', 'SOG', 'PCT', 'GWG', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'A'],
 ['', 'Andy McDonald, C', 'ANH', '82', '27', '51', '78', '16', '46', '0.95', '252', '10.7', '3', '8', '25', '0', '0'],
 ['32', 'Kristian Huselius, LW', 'CGY', '81', '34', '43', '77', '21', '26', '0.95', '173', '19.7', '6', '14', '20', '2', '2'],
 ['', 'Daymond Langkow, C', 'CGY', '81', '33', '44', '77', '23', '44', '0.95', '247', '13.4', '6', '10', '17', '1', '2'],
 ['34', 'Ilya Kovalchuk, LW', 'ATL', '82', '42', '34', '76', '-2', '66', '0.93', '336', '12.5', '7', '18', '14', '0', '0'],
 ['', 'Mats Sundin, C', 'TOR', '75', '27', '49', '76', '-2', '62', '1.01', '321', '8.4', '3', '6', '28', '1', '0'],
 ['', 'Paul Kariya, LW', 'NSH', '82', '24', '52', '76', '6', '36', '0.93', '224', '10.7', '2', '5', '20', '0', '0'],
 ['37', 'Saku Koivu, C', 'MON', '81', '22', '53', '75', '-21', '74', '0.93', '154', '14.3', '4', '11', '32', '1', '2'],
 ['38', 'Alexander Semin, RW', 'WAS', '77', '38', '35', '73', '-7', '90', '0.95', '243', '15.6', '6', '17', '21', '0', '0'],
 ['39', 'Alexander Frolov, LW', 'LA', '82', '35', '36', '71', '-8', '34', '0.87', '195', '17.9', '6', '10', '18', '1', '2']]

... and so on
```

Comment: You're a life saver, I'm new to Beautiful Soup so I've been making babysteps.